# VBA code to Multiply all the elements of column "B"in Sheet 1 with a value in cell A1 of sheet 2 and print the result in Column C

Tags: vba

In a worrkbook I have two tabs, Sheet1 and Sheet2, I want to multiply all the numbers in column B of sheet1 with a value in cell A1 of sheet 2.

Can anyone please help me with the VBA code, I am new to VBA. This is what I've tried :-

```
Sub Macro1()
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-1]*Sheet2!R[-1]C[-2]"
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("C10").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Selection.FillDown
    Range("C10").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToLeft)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("A10").Select
    Selection.End(xlUp).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will serve your purpose:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Muliply_Column ()
''assuming that Sheet("one") column B and A1 of Sheet("two") only contain numeric value

Dim xyz As Range
Dim pqr As Range
Dim r1 As Range

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("one").Activate
Set xyz = ActiveSheet.Range("B3", Cells(Application.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
''B3 cell is the starting cell of column B , adjust this to your need    
Set pqr = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("two").Range("A1")

For Each r1 In xyz
If r1.Value <> "" Then
r1.Offset(, 1).Value = r1.Value * pqr.Value
End If
Next

Set pqr = Nothing
Set xyz = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel in front of me so the code might be a bit off. Where do you want those numbers to go? Into an array? Listed in a separate column or cell?

Wouldn't defining the range, then using a For_Next give you what you need?

You will need to specify where the output goes though... otherwise it simply overwrites the iNewnumber with the next result of the multiplication. You can either store it into an Array, or spit the numbers out into cells in a column somewhere.

This sets iMultiplier to be = whatever number is listed in A1 in Sheet 2 and sets range to all cells with a value in column B.

```
iMultiplier = Sheet2.Range("A1") 
rNumbers = Sheet1.Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstant)
```

Then we do a for_next loop where it starts multiplying the value of each cell in the rNumbers range (being all cells in column B with a value) with the value of A1.

```
For Each cell In rNumbers     
   iNewnumber = cell * iMultiplier
Next cell
```